# How to remove DocuSign anchor string after signing

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any option to remove anchor string after signature on document in DocuSign.
Please suggest if anything here

Answer (score 4):

Just make the string with a white text on white background, so it's not visible.

You cannot modify the document after signing in any way. This is a legal requirement.

Comment: Can you have DocuSign remove it before the document gets signed? So I send the document via the Java API with the anchor text strings for DocuSign to put the signature fields, couldn't it then remove the Anchor Text as this is before the document has even been signed yet. We will have Merge tokens in our document that could be "[Signature: Buyer]" and that be our anchor text, so when white on white it would still take up a lot of document space. Thanks.

Comment: No, because it's a catch22, before it gets signed, meaning that the signing elements (tabs) won't be there yet and then you won't see them. You can always use white ink or just not use anchor strings and instead place the tabs using X/Y coordinates.

Comment: It will be impossible to do an X/Y Coordinate as the Document might have different text in different places based on merge token values that get put into the document at MS Word Merge time. White Ink also doesn't work because those Strings will be too long that are white and the document will look like there is a huge amount of unnecessary white space. if there was a tool in MS Word that you can place Signature tags in place, and then DocuSign finds that directly. Anchor Tags aren't that because they take up too much space. But thanks for the reply Inbar, love the help you give everyone here.

Comment: why do the strings have to be so long? you can also use a tiny font size

Comment: because the users need to see it when they are writing their MS Word Merge documents, we will be writing a MS Word Plugin, which will add Content Controls for Merge tokens as well as the ones for DocuSign. The user will see the nice text in the space that they want signatures to be. But when the document is merged and signed all those Content Controls disappear to users as the "completed" document. There are many specs that we are required to implement and those texts will be so long, and I can't do anything about it. :(

Comment: " you can also use a tiny font size" It might work, but when first put into the document it has to show in regular font size so the users can see that they placed them there.

Comment: you can replace the large/big font text string with a small, tiny font, white string before you send it to DocuSign, but after the user is done, so they user only sees the big/long strings